# How to get an image from URL and put into NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiimage, nsurl

I would like to get an image from an URL and put it into a NSArray, but doesn't work in the below codes, please help:

```
@interface DataViewController ()

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSArray *picData;

@end

@implementation DataViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *imageUrlStringAA=@"http://aaa.net/AA.png";
    NSString *imageUrlStringBB=@"http://aaa.net/BB.png";

    NSURL *urlAA=[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlStringAA];
    NSURL *urlBB=[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlStringBB];

    NSData *dataAA=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlAA];
    NSData *dataBB=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlBB];

    UIImage *imageAA=[UIImage imageWithData:dataAA];
    UIImage *imageBB=[UIImage imageWithData:dataBB];

    _picData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageAA, imageBB, nil];
```

Any ideas is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: At what point do things go wrong? Have you debugged the code at all? Are `dataAA` and `dataBB` non-nil?

Comment: FYI - NEVER load data from the network on the main thread. Very, very bad.

Comment: You should use URLConnection to download the image from URL. With your current code when image is adding to the array, image mightn't be available and its nil.

Comment: Thanks, from the log, dataAA and dataBB is nil. So I need to use NSURLConnection instead of NSURL?

Comment: You use `NSURLSession` instead of the `NSData initWithContentsOfURL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing for download anything from http protocol then Add following diction in info.plist

[image: Allow http protocol]

And now try this code:

```
@interface DataViewController ()

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSArray *picData;

@end

@implementation DataViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   NSString *imageUrlStringAA=@"http://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/antelope_canyon-360x640.jpg";
   NSString *imageUrlStringBB=@"http://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/vegeta_dragon_ball_super-360x640.jpg";

   NSURL *urlAA=[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlStringAA];
   NSURL *urlBB=[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlStringBB];

    NSData *dataAA=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlAA];
    NSData *dataBB=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlBB];

    UIImage *imageAA=[UIImage imageWithData:dataAA];
    UIImage *imageBB=[UIImage imageWithData:dataBB];
    _picData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageAA, imageBB, nil];
}
```

Comment: dataAA and dataBB will kill your app performance, freeze, stuck..you are loading it in main thread, this is bad way..kindly find a alternative way with current sdk

Comment: Why would you use an operation queue just so you can perform the network access on the main queue? The goal is to perform the network access in the background, not on the main queue. And how does this solve the original problem?

Comment: Image size to big it take minute for downloading data.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not working, same error log as the previous code.

Comment: can you give screen shot of bug?

Comment: Thank you Sakir, your code is working.  I just tried again and fixed some error in another area for getting the image.  THANKS!

Comment: sorry how to make it as answer?  I am newbie.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Do not use this code. This code is still performing the network access on the main queue. That is very bad.

Comment: Now check answer i update it without operation queue @rmaddy.

Comment: And this is now the exact same code as in the question. So there is still the problem of performing the network access on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                                 [NSURL URLWithString:@"Image URL"]]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(image!= nil){
                [[cell myimage] setImage:image];

            }else{
                UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PLACEHOLDER"];
                [[cell myimage] setImage:image];

            }


            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });
```

Try these...